# Is a Kafka source connector's poll() method guaranteed to succeed sending the message to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I understand that the poll() method contains the custom code to fetch data from the external source. Can I assume that once the poll() method successfully returns a sequence of SourceRecord objects, the same is guaranteed to be written into Kafka ? 
In other words, do I need to worry about implementing the Task in such a way as to enable returning the same set of records if called multiple times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a network exception of a leader broker could fall offline before or inbetween the producer send and any ack, so no, not guaranteed under exteme conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So in case of a failure, Kafka will rerun / recreate the task as required, and the expectation is that the task has a way to fetch the same data again right ?

Comment: There is a backoff retry loop, then the connector tasks will halt. Refer `error.tolerance` config. The expectation is that the source has a way to track sequential data, yes. For example, the JDBC source can read IDs or timestamps. A file source might track line numbers.